# Delete Column from Grid and have other columns reposition c#

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have a wpf application and I want to be able to delete a column from a grid and then have the other columns repositioned themselves (i.e. if the users deletes the first column all other columns move one to the left, if the user deletes the second column all other columns after the second one moves to the left) by the event of clicking a button. Currently I am only able to hide the items in the column, it leaves a white space which I don't want.

```
private void SetColumnWidthCol1()
    {
        Col2.Width = new GridLength(150);
        Col3.Width = new GridLength(150);
        Col4.Width = new GridLength(150);
    }

    private void SetColumnWidthCol2()
    {
        Col1.Width = new GridLength(150);
        Col3.Width = new GridLength(150);
        Col4.Width = new GridLength(150);
    }

    private void SetColumnWidthCol3()
    {
        Col1.Width = new GridLength(150);
        Col2.Width = new GridLength(150);
        Col4.Width = new GridLength(150);
    }

    private void SetColumnWidthCol4()
    {
        Col1.Width = new GridLength(150);
        Col2.Width = new GridLength(150);
        Col3.Width = new GridLength(150);
        Col5.Width = new GridLength(150);
        Col6.Width = new GridLength(150);
    }

    private void SetColumnWidthCol5()
    {
        Col1.Width = new GridLength(150);
        Col2.Width = new GridLength(150);
        Col3.Width = new GridLength(150);
        Col4.Width = new GridLength(150);
        Col6.Width = new GridLength(150);
    }

    private void SetColumnWidthCol6()
    {
        Col1.Width = new GridLength(150);
        Col2.Width = new GridLength(150);
        Col3.Width = new GridLength(150);
        Col4.Width = new GridLength(150);
        Col5.Width = new GridLength(150);
    }

    private void CloseRock_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RockLabel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        CloseRock.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    private void CloseContacts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContactsLabel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        CloseContacts.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    private void CloseFluid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FluidLabel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        CloseFluid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    private void CloseRegions_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RegionsLabel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        CloseRegions.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    private void CloseProbabilities_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        ProbabilitiesLabel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        CloseProbabilities.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    private void CloseEconomics_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EconomicsLabel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        CloseEconomics.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:syncfusion="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf"
x:Class="ItemWrapPanel.MainWindow"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="1000">
<Window.Resources>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LabelBackground" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFEFEEEE" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#E7E7E7E7" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="selectedHeaderBackground" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#F6CD1D" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#EBA32A" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col1"/>
    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col2"/>
    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col3"/>
    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col4"/>
    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col5"/>
    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col6"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Label x:Name="RockLabel"
    Background="{StaticResource LabelBackground}"
    Content="Rock Properties"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="0"
    MouseUp="RockLabel_MouseDoubleClick"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<Label x:Name="ContactsLabel"
    Content="Contacts"
    Background="{StaticResource LabelBackground}"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Grid.Row="0"
    MouseUp="ContactsLabel_MouseDoubleClick"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<Label x:Name="FluidLabel"
    Content="Fluid Properties"
    Background="{StaticResource LabelBackground}"
    Grid.Column="2"
    Grid.Row="0"
    MouseUp="FluidLabel_MouseDoubleClick" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<Label x:Name="RegionsLabel"
    Content="Regions"
    Background="{StaticResource LabelBackground}"
    Grid.Column="3"
    Grid.Row="0"
    MouseUp="RegionsLabel_MouseDoubleClick" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<Label x:Name="ProbabilitiesLabel"
    Content="Probabilities"
    Background="{StaticResource LabelBackground}"
    Grid.Column="4"
    Grid.Row="0"
    MouseUp="ProbabiltitesLabel_MouseDoubleClick"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<Label x:Name="EconomicsLabel"
    Content="Economics"
    Background="{StaticResource LabelBackground}"
    Grid.Column="5"
    Grid.Row="0"
    MouseUp="EconomicsLabel_MouseDoubleClick" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<Button x:Name="Resetbtn" Content="Restore" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Reset_Click" Margin="0,59,0,0"/>
<Button Name="CloseRock" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Click="CloseRock_Click"/>
<Button Name="CloseContacts" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,2,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Click="CloseContacts_Click"/>
<Button Name="CloseFluid" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,2,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Click="CloseFluid_Click"/>
<Button Name="CloseRegions" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,2,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Click="CloseRegions_Click"/>
<Button Name="CloseProbabilities" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,2,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" Click="CloseProbabilities_Click"/>
<Button Name="CloseEconomics" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,2,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0" Click="CloseEconomics_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: If you need the XAML I can post that up too?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Visibility.Hidden` make them `Visibility.Collapsed`.

Like -

```
private void CloseContacts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContactsLabel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    CloseContacts.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: I tried using collapsed but it just does the same as hidden, thanks anyway

Comment: really ? can you post your xaml as well plz then

Comment: and when do you call these set width methods ? seems quite complicated for a basic feature. unless you want something very specific

Comment: Yeah ok I'll attach my XAML and rest of my code too if that helps

Comment: just a suggestion - why cant you set width of all columns as Witdh="*" in xaml and get rid of most of the c# code ?

Comment: Yeah I could do that then, was just throwing it all down just now really